# How Do I Avoid This Behavior?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Say I have an entity that looks as follows

```
public Order OrderEntity 
{   
   EntityRef<Customer> CustomerEntity;   
   EntitySet<OrderDetail> OrderDetailEntity;   
   ...   
   ...
}
```

When I save a OrderEntity, L2S, will want to also save the entity in CustomerEntity and all the entities in OrderDetailEntity. Sometimes we want this behavior and sometimes we do not. For those times we do not, how to tell L2S not to do this?

Thanks - Randy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no changes made to a particular entity, L2S will not do an actual save to the database 
when you `SubmitChanges()`.  If there are changes made to a particular entity, and you execute `SubmitChanges()`, I assume you want them to take effect.

If there are changes to a particular entity, but you don't want them to take effect when
`SubmitChanges()` is called, then you have to do the work on the entities individually; 
i.e. load and save them separately from your larger entity.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399378.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If any of `OrderEntity` child objects are changed and you don't want to save the changes, i suggest that you reload `OrderEntity` with non of its child objects, make the changes then save it.